# How to like multiple times with simple like page in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I made a simple like page for a project I'm working on. I have a page with speakers and each speaker has a button to like, once clicked it is directed to my like_code php page with the speaker id and it succesfully updates the database with 1 like. This works.

Now my problem is that I can only like once, I have a variable '1' that I'm adding onto my existing like counter with an sql UPDATE everytime the button is pressed. For some reason though, I can only like every speaker once and if I manually put a higher amount of likes in my database (like 7), it gets overwritten and dropped down back to 1 when I click the like button again.

I haven't found any similar problems online so far and each like system online is very different from mine. I also don't use userids and the speakerid + likecounter are in the same table. These are the only two values I use from my database for the like code.

```
<?php 

require_once('website/script/database.php');

if(isset($_GET['idsprekers'])){
    //Get idsprekers
    $id = $_GET['idsprekers'];

    $a = "1";
    $liked = $row['likecounter'];
    $liked = $liked + $a;

    //Prepare query
    $sql = "UPDATE sprekers SET likecounter=$liked WHERE idsprekers=?";

    //$stmt = statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    //Parameter
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

    //Execute query
    $stmt->execute();


}

header("location:overzicht_spreker.php");

?>
```

Link to like a speaker on my speaker page

```
print('<div class="col-2"><a href="like_code.php?idsprekers=' . $tempId 
.'" class="btn-like"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a></div>');
```

My expected result is that when I click the like button it updates the database every time, when I click it once it would show 1 like in the database and when I click it again at a later time it would show 2 likes. Now it only shows 1 and doesn't want to budge whatsoever, unless I enter it manually.

Comment: Instead of fetching the variable into PHP, incrementing, and storing, you can simply increment in MySQL. `UPDATE sprekers SET likecounter=likecounter + 1`. This prevents conflicts as well if multiple people like at the same time

Comment: maximst96  did you checked the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SET field = field + 1` in your query itself.

```
$sql = "UPDATE sprekers SET likecounter=likecounter+1 WHERE idsprekers=?";
```

Now modified code will be like this:

```
<?php 

require_once('website/script/database.php');

if(isset($_GET['idsprekers']) && $_GET['idsprekers'] > 0 ){ //check id is not coming as 0
    //Get idsprekers
    $id = $_GET['idsprekers'];

    //Prepare query
    $sql = "UPDATE sprekers SET likecounter=likecounter+1 WHERE idsprekers=?";

    //$stmt = statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    //Parameter
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

    //Execute query
    $stmt->execute();


}else{
    die('speaker id required'); //if id didn't came, throw an error
}

// apply exit or die along with header(), otherwise code execution won't stop and will create a big security loophole.
header("location:overzicht_spreker.php");exit; 

?>
```

Note:- please pay extra attention on comments of code section.